# How to solve the the integral $\int \sqrt{(R^2 - x^2)(r^2 - x^2)}\, dx?$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I am looking for help to solve an integration problem. Any help regarding this problem will be appreciated.

> **Problem:** How to solve the following integration where $r \leq R$:
>   $$I = \int_{x = 0}^r \sqrt{(R^2 - x^2)(r^2 - x^2)}\, dx?$$

I have substituted $x=r\sin(\theta)$
but it gives nothing.

Comment: I have substituted $ x = rsin(\theta)$ but it gives nothing.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral

Answer (score 4):

This is connected to elliptic integrals. It's not necessary to make a trigonometric substitution, but we need to make the variable dimensionless:

$$x=rt$$

$$k=\frac{r}{R}$$

$$\int_{0}^r \sqrt{(R^2 - x^2)(r^2 - x^2)} ~ dx=r^2 R\int_{0}^1 \sqrt{(1 - k^2 t^2)(1 - t^2)} ~ dt$$

There are two complete elliptic integrals $E(k)$ and $K(k)$. Find the information on wikipedia page or anywhere else.

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1650863/269624) I found that this integral satisfies the equation:

$$\int_{0}^1 \sqrt{(1 - k^2 t^2)(1 - t^2)} ~ dt=E(k)-I(k)$$

Where:

$$I(k)=\frac{(1-k^2)K(k)-(1-2k^2)E(k)}{3k^2}$$

From this we conclude:

$$\int_{0}^1 \sqrt{(1 - k^2 t^2)(1 - t^2)} ~ dt=\frac{(1+k^2)E(k)-(1-k^2)K(k)}{3k^2}$$

And finally:

> $$ \int_{0}^r \sqrt{(R^2 - x^2)(r^2 - x^2)} ~ dx=  \frac{R}{3}\left((R^2+r^2)E\left(\frac{r}{R}\right)-(R^2-r^2)K\left(\frac{r}{R}\right) \right)$$